# Find a record in Mongod without ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

When I run this query( In rails console):

```
Analytic.where(:created_at.gte => start_date, :created_at.lte => end_date).only(:user_uuid).as_json
```

The response is also returning "_id" by default. I want to skip that "_id" from the response, using the query.

When I check the hash I get this:

```
#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"created_at"=>{"$gte"=>2018-06-27 06:00:00 UTC, "$lte"=>2018-06-28 05:59:59 UTC}}
  options:  {:fields=>{"_id"=>1, "user_uuid"=>1}}
  class:    Analytic
  embedded: false>
```

Which is showing that it is also asking for "_id".

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Analytic
  .where(
    :created_at.gte => start_date,
    :created_at.lte => end_date
  ).pluck(
    :user_uuid
  ).as_json
```

EDIT:

This should do the trick:

```
Analytic
  .where(
    :created_at.gte => start_date,
    :created_at.lte => end_date
  ).pluck(
    :user_uuid
  ).map {
    |uuid| {
      "user_uuid" => uuid
    }
  }
```

Or slightly more readable:

```
Analytic.where(:created_at.gte => start_date, :created_at.lte => end_date).pluck(:user_uuid).map { |id| { "user_uuid" => id } }
```

Comment: Pluck does not return the key. I want something like [{"user_uuid" : "hhj23"}, {"user_uuid" : "kjk23j3k4jk23"}]

Comment: Still... the returned type will be Array of Hashes and not Array of Analytics. Not that it is wrong, just so @SachinPrasad will be aware of it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

Analytic.select(:user_uuid).where(:created_at.gte => start_date, :created_at.lte => end_date).as_json